# How to handle the transparent status bar on iOS7 when moving a view up to make room for the keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a single view application (it is not a scroll view). When the keyboard is shown I move the whole view upwards by changing the `origin.y` and the `size.height` of `self.view.frame`, as below:

```
// self is a UIViewController
CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
rect.origin.y -= offset;
rect.size.height += offset;
```

This works perfectly for me on iOS6 because the top status bar is opaque, however on iOS7 the contents of my view now overlap with the statusbar and it looks like a mess.

Is there an easy way to clip the top of the view when I move it upwards so that the subviews aren't drawn in the same area as the statusbar? Or is there another preferred solution?

Comment: I have decided I will animate the alpha property on my view(s) which overlap the statusbar. It looks great, I just have to remember to change which views I hide if I change the layout etc.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of before and after? Interested in your solution :)